# Implement the Swift pow(base, exp)-function yourself

Tags: algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel, swift

**Task:** Implement a function, which accepts two integers and results the first number raised to the power of the second number. Both numbers have to be positive.

**Examples:**

- The arguments 4 and 3 shall return the result 64
- The arguments 2 and 8 shall return 256

**My solution (plus tests):**

```
func getPowOf(base: Int, exp: Int) -> Int {
    guard base > 0, exp >= 0 else {
        return -1
    }
    
    if exp == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    
    var result = base
    for _ in 1..<exp {
        result = (result * base)
    }
    
    return result
}

print("Result 2^0 : \(getPowOf(base: 2, exp: 0))")
print("Result 2^1 : \(getPowOf(base: 2, exp: 1))")
print("Result 2^2 : \(getPowOf(base: 2, exp: 2))")
print("Result 2^4 : \(getPowOf(base: 2, exp: 4))")
print("Result 2^10 : \(getPowOf(base: 2, exp: 10))")
print("Result 3^4 : \(getPowOf(base: 3, exp: 4))")
print("Result 4^3 : \(getPowOf(base: 4, exp: 3))")
print("Result 5^5 : \(getPowOf(base: 5, exp: 5))")
/*
 Result 2^0 : 1
 Result 2^1 : 2
 Result 2^2 : 4
 Result 2^4 : 16
 Result 2^10 : 1024
 Result 3^4 : 81
 Result 4^3 : 64
 Result 5^5 : 3125
 */
```

**What's your opinion concerning my solution? Especially the argument-checks with guard and if?**

How would you have solved the task? What can become improved?

Comment: You modified the testcase in the code from 2^8 to 2^10, but not in the output.

Comment: The base should be allowed to be `0`. A faster approach would be the exponentiation by squaring algorithm. Returning `-1` is bad design.

Comment: There is [exponentiation by squaring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021464).

Comment: Negative bases should be allowed too. Use assertions for tests. A better signature for this function could be: `(Int, UInt)->Int throws CustomOverFlowError`, it would both force the exponent to be non-negative, and handle overflows gracefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Naming

According to the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/), *abbreviations* should be avoided, unless they are terms-of-art which can be easily found by a web search. Also the “get” prefix is usually not used with Swift functions.

A term-of-art would be `pow` which is used in many programming languages. But the C math library is already imported into Swift, so defining your own `pow()` function can easily cause confusion.

I suggest something like

```
func power(of base: Int, exponent exp: Int) -> Int
```

#### Validating the input

It makes sense to require a nonnegative exponent for this *integer*-valued function. However, just returning `-1` for invalid input is bad, as it may go unnoticed and cause errors later. Calling this function with a negative exponent is a *programming error.* With a

```
precondition(exp >= 0, "exponent must be nonnegative")
```

this can be detected early (hopefully during development) because it will cause the program to terminate.

On the other hand, there is no reason to restrict the base to positive numbers. Raising zero or a negative integer to some (non-negative, integer) power is well-defined, produces an integer, and in fact already works with your existing code.

#### Small simplifications

The check for `exp == 0` can be avoided if one starts with `result = 1`. The parentheses in

```
result = (result * base)
```

are not necessary, also one can use the `*=` operator instead.

With these changes, the function would look like this:

```
func power(of base: Int, exponent exp: Int) -> Int {
    precondition(exp >= 0, "exponent must be nonnegative")
    
    var result = 1
    for _ in 0..<exp {
        result *= base
    }
    return result
}
```

#### A different algorithm

The [“exponentiation by squaring” algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) reduces the number of multiplications from \$ e \$ to \$ \lfloor \log_2 e\rfloor \$, where \$ e \$ is the exponent. This can be faster when raising a (floating point) number to a large exponent. It does not have an advantage here because the integer arithmetic will overflow anyway for larger exponents.